# Exception Handler with different return type, same error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, exceptionhandler

So, this is my first time asking in this forum and I hope i you guys can help me, sorry if my post has similar topics with others.

My question is, if i have this exception handler (Spring-mvc) :

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = MyException.class)
  @ResponseBody
  public Response responseExceptionHandler(MyException e,
      HttpServletRequest request) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return createResponse(e, request); //createresponse is a generic method i create somewhere in my class
  }
```

and as we can see it returns a Response, what if I have different return type, let's say *ResponseList*, but the same exception which is *MyException* will ExceptionHandler recognize the return type also ? or only recognize its error ?

Thanks, hope to hear good news and answers from you guys.

Comment: Exception Handlers are meant for handling exceptions thrown and not the responses which are not error/exceptions.

Comment: @ScanQR what i mean here is, if i have 2 methods (in controller) with 2 return types but they have the same error, will this controlleradvice able to different it ?

Comment: let's say, 
@ExceptionHandler(value = MyException.class)
public Response handlingResponse(..)

the other one
@ExceptionHandler(value = MyException.class)
public ResponseList handlingResponseList(...)

Comment: for all MyException exception from any method will landup on your same exception handler as it is meant for MyException

Comment: @ScanQR then what will happen if i make two methods that have same exceptionhandler ?

Comment: what the issue in that? Handler might be same but the exception should have different error codes that will differentiate your case and indicate for what reason exception was thrown no matter which handler method.

Comment: @ScanQR would like to ask more, if you have email perhaps sir ?